# How to set text both static and dynamic in a single linear layout programmatically

Tags: android

I want to display data in linear layout which is dynamic but the issue is I have 4 columns of which 1st column header is static and rest 3 are dynamic.I know how to set header dynamic what I want to know is how to set both static and dynamic in single layout.
My code

```
private void addSizeGuideTable (ProductSizingDetail productSizingDetail){
    for (int i = 0; i < productSizingDetail.getSizeGuideList().size(); i++) {
        SizeGuides sizeGuides = productSizingDetail.getSizeGuideList().get(i);
        if (i == 0) {
            addColumn(sizeGuides, true, false);
        } else if (i == productSizingDetail.getSizeGuideList().size() - 1) {
            addColumn(sizeGuides, false, true);
        } else {
            addColumn(sizeGuides, true, true);
        }
    }
}

private void addColumn(SizeGuides sizeGuides, boolean rightBorder, boolean leftBorder) {
    LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    linearLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#d8d8d8"));
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1);
    linearLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
    if (rightBorder && leftBorder) {
        linearLayout.setPadding(1, 0, 1, 0);
    } else if (rightBorder && !leftBorder) {
        linearLayout.setPadding(0, 0, 1, 0);
    } else {
        linearLayout.setPadding(1, 0, 0, 0);
    }

    addHeaders(sizeGuides, linearLayout);
    addRow(sizeGuides, linearLayout);

    ((LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_size_guide)).addView(linearLayout);
}

private void addHeaders(SizeGuides sizeGuides, LinearLayout linearLayout) {
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setText(sizeGuides.getDimension());
    tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f8f8f8"));
    tv.setSingleLine();
    tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    tv.setPadding(0, 10, 0, 10);
    tv.setTypeface(TypeFaceProvider.heavy(this));
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 1);
    tv.setLayoutParams(params);
    linearLayout.addView(tv);
}

private void addRow(SizeGuides sizeGuides, LinearLayout linearLayout) {
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeGuides.getDimensionList().size(); i++) {
        DimensionItem dimension = sizeGuides.getDimensionList().get(i);
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        if(dimension.getDimensionUnit().equalsIgnoreCase("INCH")) {
            tv.setText(dimension.getDimensionValue()+"\" ");
        }else{
            tv.setText(dimension.getDimensionValue());
        }
        tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f8f8f8"));
        tv.setSingleLine();
        tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        tv.setPadding(0, 10, 0, 10);
        tv.setTypeface(TypeFaceProvider.light(this));
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        if (i == sizeGuides.getDimensionList().size() - 1) {
            params.setMargins(0, 1, 0, 0);
        } else {
            params.setMargins(0, 1, 0, 1);
        }
        tv.setLayoutParams(params);
        linearLayout.addView(tv);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a count to add the header.

```
private static headerSetupCounter =0;
```

In your `private void addColumn(SizeGuides sizeGuides, boolean rightBorder, boolean leftBorder)`

```
if(headerSetupCounter == 0)
    addHeaders(YourCustomSizeGuide, linearLayout);
else
    addHeaders(sizeGuides, linearLayout);

headerSetupCounter++;
```

You could also implement your custom sizing (or static as you refer to it) in your
`addSizeGuideTable` where you check for the column.

```
if (i == 0) {
    // addColumn(sizeGuides, true, false);
    // Implement customised "static" column.
```